# hidden code comments even in source (html/JS)

Tags: javascript, html

Probably it sounds wierd, but is there a way to make comments kinda 'unrenderable' even while viewing a source code in a browser?

e.g.:

```
<!--I want this to be visible in my editor only -->
 <div....... </div>
```

Comment: yes if you do some dynamic scripting.

Comment: if you using a framework such as MVC you can use the render engine syntax for comments... these wont appear in view when rendered. Depending on the platform you are using you could remove using code before its displayed.

Answer (score 4):

This is not possible with pure HTML or JS. If you use a back-end like Django you can use comments that can not be seen in the browser. (but similar things should also be possible with Node.js, Flask etc. and maybe even PHP)
in Django you use {# comment here #}, Django will not render the comment to the browser and you will not be able to see it in the source code. 


Alternatively, some editors have a comments system, but then the comments only show up when you use that editor, and you can't send the source files(with comments) to a friend or colleague.

Comment: Looks like it isn't possible in regular situation to hide comments. So now i just use <?php #comment ?> if i need to comment smth big or important. :))

Comment: Yeah that should work, because the comment is never actually sent to the client.